# Transformation of a serie to integral

Tags: integration, power-series

In order to solve a problem for my preparation for a mathematical competition for undergraduate students, I have met this specific difficulty.
Let $$p_{n}(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{(-1)^k}{n+k+1}\binom{n}{k}$$, how can I show that $p'_{n}(x)=x^n(1-x)^n$, when $x\in[0,1]$?
Of course I derived the initial polynomial, I found that $$p'_{n}(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}x^{n+k}$$, but I have a difficulty in proving that $$p'_{n}(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}x^{n+k}=x^n(1-x)^n$$
I need this because the we can say that $$\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{(-1)^k}{n+k+1}\binom{n}{k}=\int_{0}^{x}x^n(1-x)^ndx$$ and if we put $x=1$, then it is possible to prove that $$\frac{3^n}{2^{4n+1}}\leq p_{n}(1)\leq 2^{-2n}$$, which is something that I have done.
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Expand $(1-x)^{n}$ usng Binomial Theorem.

Comment: Needs to be corrected.  Your formula for $p_n(x)$ does not have $x$ in it.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the binomial formula:

$$\sum_{k=0}^n {{n}\choose{k}}(-1)^k x^{n+k}=x^n\sum_{k=0}^n {{n}\choose{k}}(-x)^{k} 1^{n-k}=x^n(1-x)^n.$$

Comment: Oh of course you are right, I think it needs a $x^n$ before the series in the second equality you wrote.

Comment: Yes you are right.